Using dataset column values Lookup artifact in a foreach artifact
I'm trying to use a dataset result from a ADF lookup artifact in a foreach.  I need to use each column of the result in a query within the FOREACH artifact.
The lookup is linked to the FOREACH and the Items is set to: @activity('LookupBatchInformation').output.value
Within the Copy artifact I use a dynamic data expression to create the query as follows:
SELECT [COL1]
...
FROM [dbo].[TABLE]
WHERE [COL1] = item().COL1 AND [COL2] = item().COL2
When I Debug the pipeline, I'm getting:
Error
{
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": null,
"target": "pipeline//runid/f9f65ff3-9cfc-49d7-8f32-a61d20e27342",
"details": null,
"error": null
}
I can't seem to find an example that uses a lookup artifact as parameters in a FOREACH loop.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have a sample that uses dataset rows/columns in a FOREACH loop?
Thank you


Error { "code": "BadRequest", "message": null, "target": "pipeline//runid/f9f65ff3-9cfc-49d7-8f32-a61d20e27342", "details": null, "error": null }

The above error occurs when there is a syntax error in the query and dynamic expression.
Build your query using @concat() function in the dynamic expression like below.
@concat('select [<column_name1>] from dbo.[one] WHERE [<column_name1>] = ''',item().<column_name1>,'''AND [<column_name2>] =''',item().<column_name2>,'''')


It will give expected results.

